# graphene mutations : how does one pass arguments to schema execute

Tags: python, graphene-django

The way i have learned to update db is using mutate and this way.

```
mutate="""
mutation createPreset {
    createPreset(input: {
    projName: "SEVEN"
    }) {
      ok
      preset {
        id
        projName
      }
    }
}
"""


result = schema.execute(mutate)
print(result.data)
```

This creates a record with id and projName fields.

Say , I have 3 values,

`projName = ['SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE']`

How does one pass this as variable to schema.execute ?

Comment: If the mutation createPreset only accepts a String for property projName you need to send the mutation three times with the different values. You could change the input value to a list of strings and then iterate over it in the backend